# Why does Eclipse default to debug mode whenever I make a new C++ project?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, mingw

I am about to break something... or pull my hair out...

I just installed:

- Eclipse SDK Ver 3.7.2 (Indigo)
- CDT
- MinGW

I have those two so that I can start to develop C++ on my machine, which is using Windows-XP 32-bit.

Anyway, I got a simple hello-world up and running, and all is peachy... BUT, the problem I have noticed is that everytime I make a new C++ project, it starts it off under Debug mode. I do not know how or why this is, I have gone through just about every option I can see on the menus.

I also do not know how to quickly switch between the modes, and maybe this is hurting me as well, since I am new to Eclipse.

What I want is simple:

- Start Eclipse.
- Make a new C++ project.
- Hit build.
- Hit run. (The play button)
- Have it run as a release.
- "Do something(?)" to switch to debug mode.
- Put a breakpoint somewhere.
- Hit build.
- Hit debug button (the cockroach)
- Have me stop over lines of code.

This will cause my hair to remain on my head.

Just for context, my end goal here is Eclipse-As-IDE -> MinGW-as-Cplusplus_compliler -> OpenCV

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you care about it at all? how often do you start new projects?

Comment: @DvirVolk I want it so that I can control everything better. I am learning the ropes of eclipse so I might not need it now per se, but im my experience release runs faster than debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say the reason for starting in debug mode is that every bigger project will take time, testing and "debugging" to get to a stage where it is ready to be "released". Therefore it defaults to debug.

You can however quickly change to release mode by right-clicking on the project:
Build Configurations->Set Active->Release

For most small projects it doesn't matter what you set. When you get to bigger projects, linking to different libraries depending on whether you are debugging or building for a release, you'll be taking the time to set different parameters in eclipse for different configurations.